# Tailing file using less +F/shift-F, turn off line buffering?

Tags: tail, less, buffer

When using tail -f, it prints each character as it is written to the file, but less +F won't print until it sees a linefeed.  And if the data being written to the file does not contain linefeeds, must manually refresh by Ctrl-C Shift-F.

Any command line option to turn off line buffering?